# LINQ to find first available numbered-suffix string

Tags: c#, list, linq

Given a list of names like {`Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3`, `Name10`} I'd like to find the first available name, which in this case would be `Name4`, but if the names were contiguous, the next available would have been `Name5`.

The list is **not** sorted.

I found [Efficient algorithm to find first available name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696257/efficient-algorithm-to-find-first-available-name) which seems to have some nice algorithms, but I'm unsure if I can achieve this in LINQ.

Is it possible? Which methods will work best?

Comment: what will be the lower bound and upperbound, i suppose {1,10} in this case. m i right?

Comment: Correct, lower bound will always be 1. Total number of existing names will always be less than 255.

Answer (score 4):

Variant of Michał Turczyn code, working on empty sets and unorderdered sets. The prefix can be easily changed because it is in a variable.

```
string prefix = "Name";

int i = 0;
var available = names
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(prefix.Length)))
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .TakeWhile(x => x == ++i)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Select(x => prefix + (x + 1))
    .Last();
```

Note that a less pure LINQ version (but faster because it doesn't have to generate all the various `Select` would be:

```
int available = names.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(prefix.Length)))
                     .OrderBy(x => x)
                     .TakeWhile(x => x == ++i)
                     .LastOrDefault() + 1;

string available2 = prefix + available;
```

Without having an external variable `i` (that is always ugly when a linq has an external state):

```
int available = (Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue - 1)
    .Zip(names.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(prefix.Length)))
        .OrderBy(x => x), (x, y) => new { x, y })
    .TakeWhile(x => x.x == x.y).LastOrDefault() ?? new { x = 0, y = 0 }).x + 1;
```

Note the use of `Enumerable.Range` and `Zip` to create a secondary sequence 1...n to compare against.

Comment: I was thinking about storing prefix in a variable, to make it more *elastic*, but I assumed form OP score, that he will optimise it on his own. The core idea I wanted to present was to use helper integer and use it within `TakeWhile` method :).

Comment: I had assumed the list was sorted, but I can't guarantee that, so ordering the ints is a nice approach.

Comment: @ThunderFrame You were already putting an `OrderBy()`, but in the "wrong" place at the time I wrote the response...

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
var names = new List<string>{ "Name1", "Name10", "Name3", "Name2" };
var hs = new HashSet<int>(names.Select(n => int.Parse(n.Substring("Name".Length))));
var available = $"Name{Enumerable.Range(1, 255).Where(n => !hs.Contains(n)).First()}";
```

This gives `Name4` as the correct result. it is as fast as possible given the original list isn't sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> Names = new HashSet<string> { "Name1", "Name10", "Name3", "Name2" };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int index = Enumerable.Range(1, 255).FirstOrDefault(i => !IsNameAvailable(i));

    if (index == default(int))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All names are available!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"First non available name: Name{index}");
    }

    Console.Read();
}

private static bool IsNameAvailable(int index)
{
    return Names.Contains($"Name{index}");
}
```

Output:

> First non available name: Name4

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can be achieved with LINQ, but it has some conditions (at least my solution):

it has to have helper integer, to check indexes (consecutive numbers attached to your strings).

```
int i = 0;
string prefix = "Name";
List<string> names = new List<string>{ "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name10" };
//names.Sort();
string available = names
    .Select(n => new { name = n, index = int.Parse(n.Substring(prefix.Length)) })
    .OrderBy(a => a.index)
    .TakeWhile(a => { i++; return a.index == i; })
    .Select(a => prefix + (a.index + 1))
    .Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether i understood problem correctly or not , the reason i am doubting is because of except me all the answerers seems too much qualified,their points are freaking me out, but this is what i came up with

```
List<string> existingNames = new List<string>() { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name10" };
var availableNameList = Enumerable.Range(1, 255)
                       .Except
                        ( 
                         existingNames
                         .Select(x => Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value))
                        )
                        .OrderBy(x=>x)
                        .Select(x=>"Name"+x)
                        .ToList();
```